# Apache SSL virtual host using SNI ignores ServerName

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, http, tls, sni

I would like to serve SNI-enabled clients that send the wrong host name a 400 Bad Request, but Apache always serves the default virtual host in this situation. I cannot add a default virtual host that sends the 400 Bad Request status, because SNI-disabled clients will always get this virtual host.

It seems that the *ServerName* virtual host directive is ignored for SNI-disabled clients when I enable name based virtual hosts on an SNI-enabled Apache installation.

See the following virtual host configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.4.46:443
<VirtualHost 192.168.4.46:443>
        ServerName 192.168.4.46
        DocumentRoot /var/www/error-page/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/certificate.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.4.46:443>
        ServerName test-ssl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/valid-website/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/certificate.key
</VirtualHost>
```

If I use an SNI-disabled client, I would get the error page *regardless* of the *Host:* header I send in the request. Because I use the same certificate in both virtual hosts, I would like SNI-disabled clients to be able to still reach the second virtual host based on a match with *ServerName*.

If I'd switch the position of the virtual hosts, the website would be the default virtual host and then SNI-*enabled* clients would get the website instead of the error if they supply a wrong *Host:* in the headers.

So basically, how do I get Apache to serve an error for every wrong *Host:* header regardless of SNI support, while still serving the website when using an SNI-disabled client and serving the *right* virtual host when using an SNI-enabled client?

Comment: The `Host` header sent by an SNI-disabled client should still be respected, which I've found to be the case in my testing - the default virtual host just selects what certificate is sent to SNI-disabled clients.  Are you saying you're seeing it being served the wrong vhost in your testing, or are you just theorizing that it would be wrong?

Comment: It seems you're correct - requests sent by SNI-disabled clients still get the right virtual host served matched by the `Host` header. I think my tests were flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest answer I believe will be:

**MOD_REWRITE**

Set a cond to inspect the host header; If it is not correct, forward the request off to the error page.

Your non-error site will be the default and the rewrite-rule will live in this virtual host.

---

If there do turn out to be 'shorter/easier' options, I suspect this option will provide clear logic into how requests should be processed. This solution assumes that you want **ALL** requests regardless of SNI status to provide a matching host header for a given virtual host.

Comment: This is perfect if you want the default virtual host to enforce the server name. However, my original question was flawed, as SNI-disabled clients _do_ in fact honor the `Host` header.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ServerName in the virtualHost you want to use in error mode. It should works

Comment: This will make Apache perform a reverse lookup on the IP address and use the result as the server name, so how will that help?